# How can I create relative links from my MarkDown to GitHub raw files?

Tags: github

GitHub MD supports relative links, for example from my `README.md` I can link to code in the `Code` directory:

```
To download these scripts, [click here](Code/myscript.sh), then right-click the **Raw** button and download it
```

How can I directly link to the raw content, using a relative link like `Code/myscript.sh` (*not* an absolute link like `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myrepo/toplevel/subdir/subsubdir/myscript.sh`)?

Comment: Surprised so few views on this important question/answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

append `raw=1` to your URL

```
To download these scripts, [click here](Code/myscript.sh?raw=1).
```

I did not find this documented anywhere and discovered it by experimentation, so sharing it here.